# issue accessing dropbox

Tags: firefox, internet, firefox-extensions

Whenever I try to access [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) from my Linux booted partition, it just keeps on trying to get the information from the website and displays a blank page. It works perfectly in my windows partition though. Can't seem to figure out what goes wrong in here. Here is a [screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/u2q9u) from my browser .

Answer (score 1):

Already you have opened more number of TABS in firefox browser. As I can the bar rolling over top of the dropbox tab , its not browser issue. close few tabs and then try again. These days Firefox easily taking 200 MB of RAM and as I can see you have already opened > 10 TABS. perhaps that is the reason.

Close few tabs in your browser and then try again.